# MPI send data to all when one has finished

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I have a C program which looks in a very big file and searches for a certain thing. It works like so:

- find fill size `fseek(file_descriptor, 0, SEEK_END)`
- split in number of processes
- each process performs a binary search between its bounds

Now what I want to do is when one process finds what was searching for (basically the offset `ftell(file_descriptor)` to send it to all other processes.

My approach was something like this:

```
MPI_Irecv(&buffer..., MPI_ANY_SOURCE,... &request);
while (condition) {
    MPI_Test(&request, &test, &status);
    if (test == 1) {
        // break since data is in buffer ?
        printf("someone told us");
        break;
    }
    //code
    if (condition_for_found) {
        offset = ftell(file_descriptor);
        for (i = 0; i < numprocs; ++i) {
            MPI_Send(&offset, ...i, ...);
        }
        break; // (*)
    }
}
```

I have not posted correctly C-syntax code because I think it's a problem of approach.
What I think I lack in understanding are:

- `send` and `recv` must match in number of calls, but (*) break statement will cause `send` to be called one more time that `recv`?
- `MPI_Irecv` does not always watch for data to be received?

Running `mpiexec -n 12` will print "someone told us" once or twice out of every 5 runs.

My question is: what is the approach in sending other processes some data when one has computed it (receive should not be blocking, send could be blocking) ?

I am using openmpi-1.6 implementation on ubuntu 13.04

Comment: The logic here looks okay. Do your processes break out of the while loop? I wouldn't rely on printf statements

Comment: @kraffenetti I was writing a comment, but I guess I got it. As I said in the post, just sometimes the `printf("someone told us") is executed`. I guess the problem is in the fact the for the rest of processes, `condition` breaks them out of while, so they don't test anymore for a `send`. I'll make them wait after while and let you know what happens.